# Calculating vertex normals OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, vertex, normals

I'm trying to calculate the vertex normals for a wave, but I'm getting a chequered effect instead of the desired smooth shading.

[image]

I'm not sure if I'm passing the correct vector into the `calcNormal()` function or if something else is wrong.

Here is my wave code

```
Vector3 wave1(Sea::seaGrid[i][j].x, Sea::sinVals[k], Sea::seaGrid[i][j].z);
Vector3 wave2(Sea::seaGrid[i][j+1].x, Sea::sinVals[k], Sea::seaGrid[i][j+1].z);
Vector3 wave3(Sea::seaGrid[i+1][j+1].x, Sea::sinVals[nextK], Sea::seaGrid[i+1][j+1].z);
Vector3 wave4(Sea::seaGrid[i+1][j].x, Sea::sinVals[nextK], Sea::seaGrid[i+1][j].z);

Vector3 waveNorm1 = wave1.calcNormal(wave2);
Vector3 waveNorm2 = wave2.calcNormal(wave3);
Vector3 waveNorm3 = wave3.calcNormal(wave4);
Vector3 waveNorm4 = wave4.calcNormal(wave1);

//rest of wave
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);    
glNormal3f(waveNorm1.x, waveNorm1.y, waveNorm1.z);glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0);glVertex3f(Sea::seaGrid[i][j].x, Sea::sinVals[k], Sea::seaGrid[i][j].z);
glNormal3f(waveNorm2.x, waveNorm2.y, waveNorm2.z);glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);glVertex3f(Sea::seaGrid[i][j+1].x, Sea::sinVals[k], Sea::seaGrid[i][j+1].z);
glNormal3f(waveNorm3.x, waveNorm3.y, waveNorm3.z);glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0);glVertex3f(Sea::seaGrid[i+1][j+1].x, Sea::sinVals[nextK], Sea::seaGrid[i+1][j+1].z);
glNormal3f(waveNorm4.x, waveNorm4.y, waveNorm4.z);glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0);glVertex3f(Sea::seaGrid[i+1][j].x, Sea::sinVals[nextK], Sea::seaGrid[i+1][j].z);
glEnd();
```

This is the `calcNormal()` function

```
Vector3& Vector3::calcNormal(const Vector3 &other){

Vector3 normal = crossProduct(*this, other);

//normalises vector
float vecLength = sqrt(pow(normal.x,2)+pow(normal.y,2)+pow(normal.z,2));// length();

normal.x = normal.x / vecLength;
normal.y = normal.y / vecLength;
normal.z = normal.z / vecLength;

return normal;
}
```

and this is the `crossProduct()` function

```
Vector3 Vector3::crossProduct( const Vector3 &v1,  const Vector3 &v2 )
{
Vector3 vCrossProduct;

vCrossProduct.x = v1.y * v2.z - v1.z * v2.y;
vCrossProduct.y = v1.z * v2.x - v1.x * v2.z;
vCrossProduct.z = v1.x * v2.y - v1.y * v2.x;

return vCrossProduct;
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: Surely the normal at i,j doesn't exclusively depend on the points at i,j and i+1,j, similarly at the other wave points?.

Comment: are you saying that for waveNorm1 it should be wave4.calcNormal(wave2) instead?

Comment: No, that the normal at point (i,j) probably depends on more and other variables than the points at (i,j) and (i+1,j) and probably other points than (i+1,j) and (i,j+1) that you also have. With the disclaimer that I might have misread your question I think you might want to look at something like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_method

Comment: By the way, **don't draw polygons**! Just draw quads (`GL_QUADS`), or even better triangles (`GL_TRIANGLES`). That way you can even wrap the whole wave mesh into a single `glBegin/glEnd` block and the transition to vertex arrays is also much easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those make no sense:

> ```
> Vector3 waveNorm1 = wave1.calcNormal(wave2);
> Vector3 waveNorm2 = wave2.calcNormal(wave3);
> Vector3 waveNorm3 = wave3.calcNormal(wave4);
> Vector3 waveNorm4 = wave4.calcNormal(wave1);
> ```

By that you're calculating the cross product of the position vectors. But what you actually want are the cross products of the local differentials, i.e. differences.

I.e. (wave2 - wave1) × (wave3 - wave1)

Comment: So do I replace all the normals with (wave2 - wave1) × (wave3 - wave1)?

Comment: Not quite, since this would give you face normals, but you most certainly want vertex smooth normals. Technically what you've to do is determining the slope of the surface at at vertex position, i.e. linear idependent vectors spaning the local approximative plane making up the patch of surface around the vertex, and then take the cross product of them. There's also another way in your case: You're using a sin for the wave. Normals are the cross product of the local partial derivatives, which you can write down (`d/dx a sin(b x) = a cos(x) b`)